# how do I create rating histogram in jquery mobile just like rating bar in google play

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Can someone help me out to create a rating histogram similar to the rating histogram displayed in google play?

[image]

Tried using slider but was looking out for a better option to display histogram. Below is my code

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">

<div class="ui-block-a">5 Stars</div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><input type="range" name="slider-mini" id="slider-mini" value="76322" min="0" max="84392" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" /></div>
<div class="ui-block-c">76322</div>

<div class="ui-block-a">4 Stars</div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><input type="range" name="slider-mini" id="slider-mini" value="84392" min="0" max="84392" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" /></div>
<div class="ui-block-c">84392</div>

<div class="ui-block-a">3 Stars</div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><input type="range" name="slider-mini" id="slider-mini" value="6322" min="0" max="84392" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" /></div>
<div class="ui-block-c">6322</div>

<div class="ui-block-a">2 Stars</div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><input type="range" name="slider-mini" id="slider-mini" value="25120" min="0" max="84392" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" /></div>
<div class="ui-block-c">25120</div>

<div class="ui-block-a">1 Star</div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><input type="range" name="slider-mini" id="slider-mini" value="1532" min="0" max="84392" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" /></div>
<div class="ui-block-c">1532</div>

</div>
```

Hope to get some alternative solution that helps me to display histogram in a better way then a slider control

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the work you've done and the problem you're having that's preventing you from continuing and we'll be happy to help

Comment: just updated my post... hope to get some help

Comment: can anyone provide some insight into this... even a small head through would help

Answer (score 2):

I built a similar mock-up. The actual colored values are simply percentages 1-100% sitting inside of a block element. No jQuery used here.

Example:

```
.bar-five {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #9FC05A;
}

.bar-four {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #ADD633;
}
```

[**demo**](http://codepen.io/bphillips201/pen/vBhcb)

Comment: I am not sure on what should I apply this css class. I wanted to avoid using slider, instead wanted some other alternative. Do u have any suggestions on that??

Comment: Thanks bphillips201, i created a div and set its styling. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

To draw stars you can use raty.js https://github.com/wbotelhos/raty

Use highcharts histogram. http://www.highcharts.com/

Here is how I did it:

```
function ratingsChart (id) {
$('#rateMe').attr('robotId', id);
$('#rateMe').raty( {click: function(score, evt) {
    alert('RobotId: ' + $(this).attr('robotId') + "\nscore: " + score);
}, score: 0, hints: [ _('', 1),_('', 2),_('', 3),_('', 4),_('', 5)] } );
yaShareRobot(id);
getRobotRating(id);

$('#ratingsChart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['5 ', '4', '3', '2', '1'],
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<div style="position: relative"><img style="position: absolute; right:0" src="/images/ratyImages/star-on.png"><span style="font-size: 12px">' + this.value + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div>';
            }
        }

    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: getRobotRatingsForChart(id),
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        },
        pointWidth: 24
    }]
});
```

}